# Rewriting URLs with Mod-Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

How would I rewrite:

```
http://localhost/profile.php?user=MaFi
```

to

```
http://localhost/user/MaFi
```

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault

Comment: **Tags** ought not be used for migration requests. That's what close-votes are for.

Comment: My two cents:  I consider mod-rewrite questions generally ok for SO, since it's really just regular expressions, and usually goes hand-in-hand with some kind of MVC set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^profile.php?user=(.*)$ /user/$1      [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This just won’t work as the query is not URI part of the URI path.

Comment: Hmm... I thought for sure that worked, but further research proves me wrong.  @Mafioso - Gumbo is correct, this rule will not give you the expected results.  You should go with his answer.  I can't delete this one until it is unaccepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to redirect `/profile.php?user=MaFi` to `/user/MaFi`, try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)user=([^&]+)(&+(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ /user/%3?%1%5 [L,R=301]
```

But if actually you want to rewrite `/user/MaFi` internally to `/profile.php?user=MaFi`, try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

yoursite.com/MaFi ~ yoursite.com/profile.php?user=MaFi

```
<a href='/MaFi'>MaFi</a>

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ "/profile.php?user=$1" [L]
```

Or maybe...

yoursite.com/profile.php?user=MaFi  ~  yoursite.com/MaFi

```
<a href='/profile.php?user=MaFi'>MaFi</a>

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user=(.+)
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ "/%1" [QSA]
```

I'm not 100% on these but hopefully they help.