# Mod_rewrite dynamic URLS

Tags: mod-rewrite

An example of what I am trying to achieve, I want to rewrite

> www.website.com/index.php
>   www.website.com

and

> www.website.com/index.php?page=first
>   www.website.com/first

but also

> www.website.com/index.php?category=cat&page=second
>       www.website.com/cat/second

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are you *100%* sure you want to do the rewriting this way? It seems like this is backwards to how you usually setup rewrites. Check out **[this question](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=283865.0)** and the **[first answer](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=283865.0#msg_1347389_extra_info)** to see what I mean.

I'm going to go out on a limb and ask that maybe you want to have the URLs **in the browser** look like:

```
http://www.website.com/cat/second
```

and that you want your **php application** to then *receive*:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?category=cat&page=second
```

In which case you would want something like

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# note this first rewrite would be redundant in 99.999% of cases, apache expects to serve index.php for the /
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [last]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [last]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [nocase,last]
</IfModule>
```

If I'm wrong, then Ivan c00kiemon5ter V Kanak's answer will do you right. And I'm then also curious about what kind of situation you are in where you want to do "anti-rewriting" :)

Comment: I like your approach better than mine. +1 from me
hadn't thought of it, that way :) thanks

Comment: @Ivan c00kiemon5ter - hey thanks. I'm curious what @user782958 will tell us they were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # you may want to check other uses of R
    RewriteRule ^/index.php$ / [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/index.php?page=(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/index.php?category=(.*)&page=(.*) /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can probably fit the last two in one line, playing the regexes.
Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971555/rewriting-urls-with-mod-rewrite) and you may want to look up ServerFault for more.
Many questions like this around.