# How to generate clean URLs with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I have a website generated by PHP scripts and I would really love the URLs to look professional and clean using mod_rewrite.

my current URL:

> site.com/view.php?category=bags&section=computer_bags&gallery=don_rolege

and I would like to turn that ugly URL into something like this:

> site.com/bags/computer_bags/don_rolege

I searched all over the internet for a solution, but I could not get the code work particularly for this.

Any help would  be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod_rewrite dynamic URLS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236091/mod-rewrite-dynamic-urls) - Your current URL looks clean to me, however what you want to achieve has been asked before, please do your homework first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your URLs always have category, section and gallery, no more, no less.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /view.php?category=$1&section=$2&gallery=$3 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very clear and detailed tutorial on how to set this up to your liking:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgCW2x5QCXo

It also troubleshoots any server errors you may find on the way.