# URL Routing method for core php

Tags: php, routes, url-routing, sef, clean-url

I have web site in core php and I want to make my SEF URL.
In my web site for transferring control from one page to other i have used something like

```
    header("Location: edit.php?id=12");
```

I read one article but couldn't get it how to implement it.

[Link of article](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/)

So how i can make url to read like "mysite.com/usr/edit"
I read lot on google i got the idea that i need to do something in .htaccess but i dont know what needs to do with url in php so i dont have to change major code in site.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: mod_rewrite. plenty of answers on this site about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod_rewrite dynamic URLS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236091/mod-rewrite-dynamic-urls)

Comment: possible dupe in the essence of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022509/php-dynamic-db-page-rewrite-url

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the .htaccess code given below:

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

after creating .htaccess file with above code. You will have all the stuff after the file name ex. "/usr/edit" in the GET parameter $GET['url']. After that you can do anything.
Here is the working example of my MVC framework: https://bitbucket.org/ManthanB/my-framework/

You can contact me for further information.