# How To Rewriting URLs with Mod-Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

How would I rewrite:

```
http://mydomain.com/?v=service
http://mydomain.com/?v=pfolio
```

To

```
http://mydomain.com/service
http://mydomain.com/pfolio
```

I am have tried many ways but have not figured it out. Please give a suggestion.

I already use

```
RewriteRule ^/?v=(.*)$ /v/$1      [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Rewriting URLs with Mod-Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971555/rewriting-urls-with-mod-rewrite).

Comment: Sorry, please read through the explanation of how to ask questions here. You definitely should add details about what you already have (tried) and what it is that is not working with that. You should show that you made effort to solve the question yourself before asking.

Comment: sorry,I add this in my post @arkascha

Answer (score 0):

This would be the version for the server configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/$ /%1      [R=301,L]
```

Or, if there might occur more query parameters something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^/$ /%1      [R=301,L,QSA]
```

When placed inside a `.htaccess` style file you have to *remove* the `/` from the pattern in the RewriteRule (so just `^$`).

But I am skeptical what this really is what you are really looking for. Usually people want to do the opposite of this... Maybe you should also explain what is the idea behind your attempt. So your situation, *what* you want to happen, not *how*.