# .htaccess url rewrite with external site parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an out page that is used to redirect to external sites. The out page uses GET to retrieve the external site link but I cant get the URL rewrite to work correctly when the external site has a URL parameters. I want to change the following

From:
http://www.example.com/out.php?url=http://www.externalsite.com?abc=def

To:
http://www.example.com/out/http://www.externalsite.com?abc=def

Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
RewriteRule ^out/(.*) out.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works but the ?abc=def is lost during the rewrite. Is there a way to include this in the URL rewrite? Thanks

Comment: use urlencoding, safer, valid, search SO for examples, lots of examples ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewriting URLs with Mod-Rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971555/rewriting-urls-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: With the `QSA` flag the `abc=def` section won't be *lost*, just *merged*. You **cannot** have 2 query strings in the same URL, your first example URL is therefore broken, that's why Apache won't generate it. Extract the query string another way or use a small PHP script for more finegrained control.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /out.php?url=%1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

You will need to capture the external URI from `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable here.

Comment: You should never match on `THE_REQUEST`, there might be tons of junk in there. Match on `REQUEST_URI` instead.

Comment: Yes, all that junk (the protocol and the method) are in there. Like I said, junk. And because of that, your condition erroneously matches on  wrong URLs like `/i/am/out/today`. If you just need to match on the URI, just use `REQUEST_URI` and use valid start-of-string matching. And yes, startling to have such a high rep user like you bring something extremely off topic like rep into this. I'll admit I didn't read the question enough to see it was about the  query string part, but that doesn't make your solution any better, which was all I was commenting on.

Comment: Ok deleting my earlier comment since I shouldn't bring reps here. But May I know how protocol and method becomes junk. What I meant was that  using `RewriteCond` is mandatory here and just capturing text from `RewriteRule` will be erroneous.

Comment: The actual valid way would be to match correctly on the pure URI and then, given that he wants 2 `?` sections in his result, manually force the `{QUERY_STRING}` variable in there. However I do highly doubt that Apache allows that and doesn't correct it to a URL-encoded alternative internally anyway.