# How can I replace query and fragments with only the hierarchical part, while still querying data

Tags: php, url

So, I was wondering how I can replace the query data situated after the hierarchical part in a URI, while still querying data with PHP.

Basically, I am trying to change this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/post.php?id=10910
```

into this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/post/10910
```

The `post.php` file contains the script to display the specified "post" from the ID provided in the query, loaded from a file. I am trying to format the URL so there is no query data needed to view the post, only a clean hierarchical format.

My wild guess is that there is some PHP function that can decode the provided URL, though I am not too sure how this is done/is possible.

**I do know I could create a "post" directory, then put a subdirectory for every single post and put an index file, but this isn't very efficient and is not what I am trying to achieve.**

I hope this is possible without doing what I just said, any other question on StackOverflow answering this one or online guides would help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewriting URLs with Mod-Rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971555/rewriting-urls-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @Dragon I don't really know about this Mod-Rewrite, nor am I using it.

Comment: You need to use htcaccess

Comment: @Hudixt And how can I achieve that? Sorry if I sound like an idiot, I'm more of a coder than managing a web server... EDIT: So I need to use what Dragon's suggested thread is about, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `.htcaccess` file and paste the code below in it.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)id=([^&]+)(&+(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ /post/%3?%1%5 [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps you